# Leetcode coin change timeout

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change

Following input gets timeout, if 19 -> 18 or less, it gets through.

```
[1,2,5]
19
```

```
// e.g. n === [1, 2, 5]
// e.g. t === target sum 
// c === counter, count each level
// h === hash, memo
var cc = function(n, t, c, h) {
    // index
    const index = t;
    // if we saw before, return it
    if(h[index]) {
        return h[index];
    }
    else if(t === 0) {
        // we use all the target, return the counter
        return c;
    }

    // mi === minimum counter
    let mi = Infinity;
    // e.g. we loop [1, 2, 5]
    for(let i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
        // only allow positive
        if(t-n[i] >= 0) {
            // recursive
            // mi === Infinity
            // t-n[i], consume it
            // c+1, increase the counter
            // h, pass down the hash
            mi = Math.min(mi, cc(n, t-n[i], c+1, h));
        }
    }

    // Update h[index] when mi < h[index]
    h[index] = mi < h[index] ? mi : h[index];
    return mi;
}


var coinChange = function(n, t) {
    const res = cc(n, t, 0, {});
    const out = res === Infinity ? -1 : res;
    return out;
};
```

Anyone got idea what went wrong?

Comment: For someone who does not know this language (javascript ?), it is not clear if `h` array information got in one path is seen when going through another path (i.e. another `i` index). If not, you need a global `h` array.

Comment: If you're expecting someone to help you debug code, please clearly name your variables. You could add more comments in the code, too, about what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: @Damien sorry, updated.

Answer (score 1):

There's at least one problem with the code. To see one, change this line:

```
h[index] = mi < h[index] ? mi : h[index];
```

to this:

```
console.log(`Before: t: ${ t }, mi: ${ mi }, h[index]: ${ h[index] }`);
h[index] = mi < h[index] ? mi : h[index];
console.log(`After: t: ${ t }, mi: ${ mi }, h[index]: ${ h[index] }`);
```

and call:

```
console.log(coinChange([1,2,5], 3));
```

Another problem, I think, is the discrepancy between wanting to update the result recorded in `h[index]` but at the same time wanting to return the result stored in it before we can make that update.

Imagine that we can reach target 0 in all kinds of ways, so think about what happens currently if the first recursive branch gets there with a path of many steps.

Answer (score 1):

The following is able to pass the test cases.

Fixed when to update the hash

```
// keep it infinity or 0 or positive
h[index] = (h[index] === undefined ? mi : mi < h[index] ? mi : h[index]);
```

The counter only happened inside the func. No mixed up

```
result = cc(n, t-n[i], h)
```

```
var cc = function(n, t, h) {
    // index
    const index = t;
    // reach 0, re 0
    if(t === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if(h[index] !== undefined) {
        // hash
        return h[index];
    }

    // min
    let mi = Infinity;
    // loop coin
    for(let i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
        // posi, get in
        if(t-n[i] >= 0) {
            // return count or hash
            mi = Math.min(mi, cc(n, t-n[i], h)+1);
        }
    }

    // keep it infinity or 0 or positive
    h[index] = (h[index] === undefined ? mi : mi < h[index] ? mi : h[index]);
    return h[index];
}


var coinChange = function(n, t) {
    const res = cc(n, t, {});
    const out = res === Infinity ? -1 : res;
    return out;
};
```

Comment: How can this, `h[index] = (h[index] === undefined...` ever evaluate as "defined"? Don't we return its value at the top of the `cc` function if `h[index]` is defined? Wouldn't it always be undefined at that point, so we can just set it to `mi`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'd be easier if we'd use an extra memory to solve the problem:

```
const coinChange = function(coins, amount) {
    const inf = Math.pow(2, 31)
    const dp = []
    dp[0] = 0

    while (dp.length <= amount) {
        let curr = inf - 1
        for (let index = 0; index < coins.length; index++) {

            if (dp.length - coins[index] < 0) {
                continue
            }

            curr = Math.min(curr, 1 + dp[dp.length - coins[index]])
        }

        dp.push(curr)
    }

    return dp[amount] == inf - 1 ? -1 : dp[amount]
};
```

Python:

```
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins, target):
        dp = [0] + [float('inf')] * target
        for index in range(1, target + 1):
            for coin in coins:
                if index - coin >= 0:
                    dp[index] = min(dp[index], dp[index - coin] + 1)
        
        return -1 if dp[-1] == float('inf') else dp[-1]
```

Using a helper function (Java):

```
class Solution {
    public int coinChange(int[] coins, int target) {
        if (target < 1)
            return 0;
        return helper(coins, target, new int[target]);
    }

    private int helper(int[] coins, int rem, int[] count) {
        if (rem < 0)
            return -1;
        if (rem == 0)
            return 0;
        if (count[rem - 1] != 0)
            return count[rem - 1];
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int coin : coins) {
            int res = helper(coins, rem - coin, count);
            if (res >= 0 && res < min)
                min = 1 + res;
        }

        count[rem - 1] = (min == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : min;
        return count[rem - 1];

    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question, "what went wrong?" (with their implementation)

Comment: Heh. It's not difficult to find ready made solutions online for the coin change problem. Surely, that's not what we're here for.